# Using Styled-components gives Invalid Hooks Call error and Type Error in my React app

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, styled-components

When trying to render my react app, it works if my components are vanilla html/css, like using a h1 tag, but as soon as I use my styled-components, it throws a bunch of errors, including:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component.

and

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useDebugValue')

and

> The above error occurred in the <styled.div> component:
> http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4962:68
> Sidebar
> App
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior."

Here is my Sidebar `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import {SidebarContainer} from './SidebarElements'

const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <SidebarContainer>hi</SidebarContainer>
        </>
    )
}


export default Sidebar;
```

Here is the Sidebar `elements.js`

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const SidebarContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 37px 10px 10px;
    gap: 68px;

    width: 563px;
    height: 1574px;

    background: #FFFFFF;

    flex: none;
    order: 0;
    align-self: stretch;
    flex-grow: 0;
`
```

And finally here is the `app.js`

```
import './App.css';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

How can I fix this? Is styled-components the issue?

Comment: I think the styled component is a react hook and you use it in a nonfunctional component so move your SidebarContainer to the Sidebar page

Comment: Generally this  occurs when there is library duplication in your dependencies. make sure you only have one version of Styled Components

Comment: @monim How can I ensure that I only have one version of Styled Components?

Comment: @MeetMajevadiya what you said works, but do you know why it works? I'm still confused